# Is a PoW-based Ethereum private chain a permissioned blockchain?

Tags: private-blockchain, permissioned-chain

If I creat a ethereum private chain through geth. Is the Ethereum private chain a permissioned blockchain?

Comment: Could you add more details about how you create your private chain?

Comment: I followed the guide: https://medium.com/mercuryprotocol/how-to-create-your-own-private-ethereum-blockchain-dad6af82fc9f

Comment: A PoW blockchain is typically permissionless. But you can add a permission layer above with whitelisting IPs. There are other blockchains that have an explicit authorization scheme like Quorum.

Answer (score 1):

Your blockchain is not permissioned, i.e. is uses the same rules as Mainnet.  Though, in order to connect to it and use it, one will need to:

1. Know IP/port of some of your nodes
2. Be able to connect to your nodes
3. Have your genesis block (probably it is possible to download it from node)